# What is this small green bug with long legs and antennae, in New Zealand?

Tags: identification, pests, insects, beans

I have found an insect sitting on one of my plants, in Auckland, New Zealand.

It is sitting on a broad bean leaf about 6 cm wide

[image: Insect]

Is this a friend or foe?

Comment: You have cooler insects in auckland, not fair! I didn't even know we had katydid in nz. I would have thought it was a tiny weta, but it looks just like J Musser's picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is a nymph of [*Caedicia simplex*](http://www.terrain.net.nz/friends-of-te-henui-group/local-insects/long-horned-grasshopper.html), (common name Katydid, Kiki Pounamu). These are [native to Australia and New Zealand](http://books.google.com/books?id=3gQ4AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=caedicia%20simplex%20in%20new%20zealand&source=bl&ots=qesEzi52yN&sig=mKTmzqFw_f4QECn_OZnad-43lb0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yluDVMLxK-HdsASKr4GgCw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=caedicia%20simplex%20in%20new%20zealand&f=false). They do feed on plants, but don't usually cause much damage unless the populations are great.

There are many color variants. Here's a comparison pic of a nymph that looks similar to yours:

[image]